Multiple regression assumptions

Hi all,
I am doing assumption checks on the below, and my Achilles heel is discerning violations from scatterplots (scatterplot attached via the link above) like the one I have linked. I have scoured the web as these graphs threw me a bit, given they are technically still evenly clustered around the line, but some of the points are clustered right next to each other. All I could discern from online is that the assumptions hold if there is no discernible pattern or funnel shape (which I feel as though there isn’t).
If there is a violation, would I typically perform the transformation on the DV or IV (from what I can see online, it is typically done to the DV?)
Thank you!
